# ASP.NET Core - Serilog in default the logger

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, serilog

I want to use Serilog in my ASP.NET Core app to log to a file. I have installed package `Serilog.AspNetCore` (it has dependencies to the `Serilog.Settings.Configuration` and `Serilog.Sinks.File`, so I guess I don't need any other package).

My goal is to achieve logging in my controllers like this:

```
...
private ILogger _log;
public MyController(ILogger<MyController> logger)
{
   _log = logger;
}
...

public ActionResult<MyResponse> Foo([FromRoute] Guid fooGuid)
{
   _log.LogError("error test");
}
```

In my `appsettings.json` I have this configuration:

```
"Serilog": {
    "Using": [],
    "MinimumLevel": "Information",
    "WriteTo": [
      { "Name": "Console" },
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "patch": "D:\\Log\\log.log"
        }
      }
    ],
    "Application": "Centralized logging application"
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
```

and my `Program.cs` looks like this:

```
  public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
          .ConfigureLogging((context, logging) =>
          {
            logging.ClearProviders();
            logging.AddSerilog().AddConfiguration(context.Configuration);
          })
          .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
          {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
          });
```

I think the problem is in the `Program.cs` file. What is the most easy way how to achieve this kind of loging to the file? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. you have a typo on your appsettings.json. It should state
   `"path": "D:\\Log\\log.log"`
2. your `CreateHostBuilder` method, should include:

   ```
   Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
   .UseSerilog()
   ```
3. your `Main` method should include

   ```
   // reading from appsettings.json the logging settings
   var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
       .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
       .Build();
   Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
       .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
       .CreateLogger();
   ```